# Spring/Java Mail:The sender is always the spring.mail.username. The FROM address is being ignored

Tags: spring-boot

I send mail using `SimpleMailMessage`. Everything is working nicely. But I don't know why on the receiver side shows `spring.mail.username's` address and not the From Adress.
Each mail sent to the right address but from the address mail which is created in property spring.mail.username
What method will use for this? Is there any method available in `SimpleMailMessage` Class?

`resources/application.properties`

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username = ***@otherdomain
spring.mail.password = ***
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Code

```
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}

public void sendMail(String fromEmail,String toEmail, String subject, String message) {

    var mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
    mailMessage.setFrom(fromEmail);

    mailMessage.setTo(toEmail);
    mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mailMessage.setText(message);


    javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change `FROM EMAIL` address since it's `hard coded: spring.mail.username = ***@otherdomain` in `resources/application.properties`.

But you set the name using `MimeMessagePreparator`

```
try {
   MimeMessagePreparator preparator = (mimeMessage) -> {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
        helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@gmail.com", "JACK SPARROW"));
        helper.setTo("example@gmail.com");
        helper.setSubject("Sample email");
        helper.setText("Message from ....", true);
    };          
    javaMailSender.send(preparator);
  } catch (MailException exception) {
    throw exception;
}
```

Comment: Same issue the mail is not sent with the From Adress

Comment: It's not possible to change `FROM EMAIL` address since it's `hard coded` in `resources/application.properties`.

Comment: So what to do?
When i delete the codein app.prop i receive a wrong message

Comment: Because i need it to be changed every time with the Email adress of the sender

Comment: It's not possible. Unless you create a conditional bean with all sender details `user name(email) & password`.

Comment: there is an other solution to send mail without SMTP ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Google it or ask in StackOverflow.